# How to insert multiple properties into mongodb using mongoose in node?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my collection schema and model

```
const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    isGold: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        reuired: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
    }
}));
```

I am using the following code to insert data into MongoDB collection

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = validateCustomer(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    let customer = new Customer({
        name: req.body.name,
        isGold: req.body.isGold,
        phone: req.body.phone
    });
    customer = await customer.save();
    res.send(customer);
});
```

And this is the validate function

```
function validateCustomer(customer) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        phone: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        isGold: Joi.boolean()
    };

    return Joi.validate(customer, schema);
}

exports.Customer = Customer;
```

`exports.validateCustomer = validateCustomer;

I am getting 400 bad request when I send a request using postman using the JSON in the body for the parameters,

```
"isGold" is not allowed
```

The above shown is the error I get. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you share the frontend request codes

Comment: I think this is not a mongoose issue but it is validation error from your `validateCustomer` function and `Joi` module

Comment: It is just a middleware. I am building this to learn middleware. No frontend for this @Karl L

Comment: @KeshavaPranath, jsut trying to check how did you pass the request body like